# Missing video codec in Quicktime

Tags: video, codec, quicktime

I have a quicktime video recorded on a Atoms Shogun.

When I tried to play the file it is only playing the audio and no video is coming up at all.

Delving deeper, I found out that no codec for the video was embedded in the file, only audio.

Is there any way to add the file codec to it?

---

```
General
Complete name                    : L:\9e550a82-d3ed-460f-a10d-f25be5c87a03.mov
Format                           : MPEG-4
Format profile                   : QuickTime
Codec ID                         : qt  
File size                        : 33.3 GiB
Duration                         : 1h 52mn
Overall bit rate                 : 42.3 Mbps
Encoded date                     : UTC 2024-12-01 19:09:30
Tagged date                      : UTC 2024-12-01 19:09:30
Writing library                  : Apple QuickTime

Video
ID                               : 2
Duration                         : 1h 52mn
Bit rate mode                    : Constant
Bit rate                         : 36.0 Mbps
Width                            : 1 920 pixels
Height                           : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio             : 16:9
Frame rate mode                  : Constant
Frame rate                       : 25.000 fps
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)               : 0.694
Stream size                      : 28.4 GiB (85%)
Language                         : English
Encoded date                     : UTC 2024-12-01 19:09:30
Tagged date                      : UTC 2024-12-01 19:09:30

Audio
ID                               : 1
Format                           : PCM
Format settings, Endianness      : Big
Format settings, Sign            : Unsigned
Codec ID                         : in24
Duration                         : 1h 52mn
Bit rate mode                    : Constant
Bit rate                         : 4 608 Kbps
Channel(s)                       : 4 channels
Sampling rate                    : 48.0 KHz
Bit depth                        : 24 bits
Stream size                      : 3.63 GiB (11%)
Language                         : English
Encoded date                     : UTC 2024-12-01 19:09:30
Tagged date                      : UTC 2024-12-01 19:09:30
```

Comment: Open the file in [Mediainfo](http://www.mediaarea.net) and show its full readout here.

Comment: @Mulvya I have, which is where I saw the missing codec information. It is supposed to have Avid DNxHD but it is missing

Comment: Yes, you have, but paste it here.

Comment: @Mulvya sorry, its updated now

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you described what happened and how you broke the file. If I should guess, I would think you tried to take out the video stream of a mxf file and messed up the file structure - but that's just a guess. In any case, I don't understand why you think you need dnxhd if mediainfo outputs your file as mp4. As far as I know dnxhd is not a valid codec to be encapsulated in a  mp4 container.

Comment: @HansMeiser we recorded the session, and now it isn't playable. there was nothing out of the ordinary to it. the reason we say the codec info is because another file from the same recorder has it listed in mediainfo, so the comparison between them is that's whats missing. and when you put the hard drive back in the recorder to just keeps alternating between dnxhd and prores because it doesn't know what format to play it as

Comment: Did you try ffmpeg repair?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to repair the file with [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html), a free command-line tool, like so

```
ffmpeg -analyzeduration 1G -i input.mov -c copy -map 0 out.mov
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try two solutions, obviously on backups of the files, not the originals. First there is the 'untrunc' tool which tries to copy over additional information from a working file into a broken file: https://github.com/ponchio/untrunc

Then there is AtomicParsley which allows you to view file information on Mov / mp4 files on a very detailed level. Probably you can compare a working and a broken file and try to manually add the codec information.

http://atomicparsley.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0):

If you need the Avid DNxHD codec, Avid offer it for free, for Quicktime (Mac and Windows):
http://avid.force.com/pkb/articles/en_US/download/en423319

Comment: I don't need the codec itself, I need the codec data in the header of the file